# Combine WPF Window in windows forms project in a single application . it is a good practice?

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have a windows form project, and I started to develop in WPF.
I want to use a XAML file and windows in my windows form project. this is a good practice to do?

Comment: I have to ask. Why did you start developing in wpf when the project is a WinForms application?

Comment: @GuidoG Because it is a newer technology and this is the way to learn it

Comment: Is it good practice? Not in my opinion. Better rewrite the complete application in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will share some experiences i have faced using both WPF and WinForms together.
Technically its possible to use the WPF window in winforms project.

But the feature of WPF Window will be lost if we do so, they are:

1. Transparency - the styling of WPF window wont be transparent if its
   shown from windows forms.
2. Graphics - the enhanced GUI of WPF window would be lost.

If you think you can manage these hurdles, you can go ahead with using the WPF Window.

Thanks.